# Lifetime of function behaves differently in function pointer assignment and initialization

Tags: functional-programming, rust

See the below example

```
fn fx(x: i32) -> i32
{
    x
}

fn test_Functor()
{
    // case 1. Initialization
    let myFunctor: &Fn(i32) -> i32 = &fx ;

    // case 2. Assignment
    //let myFunctor: &Fn(i32) -> i32;
    //myFunctor= &fx ;

}
```

This can compile. 
If I comment case 1 and uncomment case 2. I got an error

```
   Compiling study_rust v0.0.1 (main.rs)
src/main.rs:45:17: 45:19 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
src/main.rs:45     myFunctor= &fx ;
                               ^~
src/main.rs:44:36: 47:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 44:35...
src/main.rs:44     let myFunctor: &Fn(i32) -> i32;
src/main.rs:45     myFunctor= &fx ;
src/main.rs:46
src/main.rs:47 }
src/main.rs:45:5: 45:21 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 45:4
src/main.rs:45     myFunctor= &fx ;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:45:5: 45:21 help: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
src/main.rs:45     myFunctor= &fx ;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `study_rust`.
```

Why? Is it a bug?
I am using rustc 1.5.0

```
rustc 1.5.0 (3d7cd77e4 2015-12-04)
```

Comment: FYI `&Fn(...) -> ...` isn't a function pointer, it's a reference to a trait object. `let z: fn(i32) -> i32 = ...` would be a function pointer.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is not a bug. Note that it is also producing the same error without function pointers.

```
// this compiles
let a: &i32 = &3;
```

vs

```
let a: &i32;
a = &3;
   //^ error: borrowed value does not live long enough
```

The two pieces of code above are not equivalent. A lifetime starts at the point where you bind a variable (`let a: &32`), not where you assign it (`a = &3`). If you split the two, like in the second case, you're saying that the lifetime for the &i32 is expected to start at the `let a: &i32` line, which the compiler can't guarantee in the general case.

For instance, imagine if you did:

```
// does not compile
let a: &i32;
{
    let b = 3;
    a = &b;
} // b is out of scope, so a can't still contain a live reference here
```

you CAN make this work, but you explicitly need to tell the compiler that b is static (the static lifetime outlives everything), like this:

```
   let a: &i32;
   static b: i32 = 3;
   a = &b;
```

or (in your original case):

```
let myFunctor: &Fn(i32) -> i32;
static F: fn(i32) -> i32 = fx;

myFunctor= &F;
```

Comment: In your example it works as you say. But the point is the lifetime of the constant 3 is in the same stack as 'a'. However, fx is a function defined in the module which will be not gone even after the scope of test_Functor.

Comment: Yes, lifetimes are a bit too strict in some scenarios; they start with a binding and they end at the end of the block containing the binding, so they can reject valid code on some occasions. In the rust-lang/rust and rfcs repos you may find mentions of "non-lexical" lifetimes, that should make the compiler smarter, but I'm not sure if/how that work is proceeding

Comment: Thanks. I did not know the "lexical/non-lexical lifetime" causes I am new to rust. Will read more on it. But in my example above I think lexically the compiler should already know very clear that 'fx' has longer lifetime then 'myFunctor'. Another point is I believe there is no difference in term of lifetime between case 1 and case 2. That is inconsistency there.

Comment: @palazzotrain I added an alternative that should work in your case

Comment: thanks it works. [rust-lang issues confirmed that this is not bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/30456)

Answer (score 1):

Can it be linked to `const` vs `static`?

```
static i:usize = 0usize;

fn test_Functor()
{
    // case 2. Assignment
    let myFunctor: &usize;
    myFunctor= &i ;

}
```

It compiles when `i` is `static` but not when i is `const`. 
From the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/const-and-static.html), it is said that static aren't inlined ...